# Undelete files from amazon EC2 EBS

Tags: amazon-ec2

I deleted a bunch of files accidentally from an amazon Instances attached EBS volume.

- I shutdown the AMI,
- detached the volume,
- started a new AMI, and attached the volume to the new AMI
- ran  recoverng the files using extundelete.

Nothing is recovered into the RECOVERED_FILES directory.

Am I missing something? Is there some other way?

Comment: I guess you got to try standard ext3 undelete software or something like that, based on file system that you've formatted the volume to. Good luck.

Comment: extundelete is one I know ... is there another?

Comment: I've had luck with photorec. On Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install testdisk; sudo photorec /d TARGETDIR /dev/DEVICE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to say that you are screwed, unless you snapshotted the EBS volume recently.